# Use public for prod environment only

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using `ng build --prod` to build my application but I get about 200 errors:

[image]

Most of the errors are because I have used `private` instead of `public`. I don't get this. Why can I use `private` in TypeScript if JavaScript can't do anything with it? What's the point of `private` then?

Does that mean I have to change ALL privates to publics? If so, is it possible to keep my privates for the dev environment and use publics for prod environment only?

Comment: If you are trying to access a variable from component.js in your component.html, you need to expose your variables thus make it public.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11978

Answer (score 0):

In typescript, private, means "private to my component written in typescript". When accessing from the corresponding view (the html part), you can access only public members.

AFAIK, there is no "internal between us" and visibility modifier. For this reason, you could use a naming convention to help you discriminate who is the consumer.